# Time coming wrongly but Date is correct in swift

Tags: swift, time, dateformatter

I am getting date in textfield from datepicker.. in textfield getting correct date and time but from dateFormatter time not coming correctly but date coming perfectly

**here is my code**

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"
  let dateFormate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateLabel.text!)
    
    print("out put \(dateLabel.text!)")//log out put 8/25/20, 3:40 PM
    print("out put  \(dateFormate)")  // out put  Optional(2020-08-25 10:08:00 +0000)
```

**i am getting correct date but wrong time why?**

> log out put 8/25/20, 3:40 PM //textfield o/p

> out put  Optional(2020-08-25 10:08:00 +0000) // dateFormate o/p

where am i mistake, please help me with code.

Comment: This probably has to do with timezone. Printing a `Date` object always prints UTC time. What is the timezone of the date string in `dateLabel`?

Comment: What is the problem here, as stated this is only how the date is printed but what is your end use of this date object?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson.. if i give timezone.. then o/p like `(2020-08-25 17:32:00 +0000)` but i need like `8/25/20, 5:32 PM ` i need 12hrs formate.. how to do that

Comment: The output is just a text representation of the date, there is no 12 or 24 hour format in a Date object. Given your earlier questions and also this one you really need to understand the difference between a Date object and the text representation of a date. Only the latter has a format. So again, read up on what a Date object is so that you properly understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, you first need to create a `DateFormatter` to parse the date string, that you are getting from the `dateLabel`, to a `Date` object:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy, h:m a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "in") // here place your locale identifier
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateLabel.text!)
```

and then a new `DateFormatter` to convert your Date object to the format that you want to print. For example:

```
let outputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "M-d-yyyy, h:m a"
outputDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "in")
print(outputDateFormatter.string(from: date!))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: (dateLabel.text!))
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))
```

Comment: if i give like this.. getting time in 24hrs formate i need 12 hrs formate.. o/p i am getting `out put  Optional(2020-08-25 17:32:00 +0000)` i need like out put `8/25/20, 5:32 PM`

Comment: @iOSApp printing a `Date` object always shows tha date in UTC time zone and with a specific format. To go back to your original date string you have to print your date object using the same `DateFormatter`. So if the above code is OK in parsing, you just have to replace the `print(date!)` with `print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))`

Comment: @gcharita not for out put my time zone should be in 12hrs formate.. please help me here

Comment: @gcharita.. time should come like 5:32 PM

Comment: @iOSApp what is the timezone of the date string you getting from `dateLabel`?

Comment: @gcharita dateLabel will be like this `8/27/20, 5:50 PM`

Comment: @iOSApp yes, but in UTC timezone?

Comment: @gcharita okay, but how do i get 12hrs time formate.. currently i am getting 24hrs formate na

Comment: @iOSApp currently this answer's code will output date in 12 hour format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220425/discussion-between-iosapp-and-gcharita).